# Quotient ring of sequences for an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have the following here:

> Let $R$ be the ring of sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$with entries $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $I=\{(a_n)_n\in R|a_n=0 \text{ for all } n<5\}.$
> a) Show that $I$ is an ideal of $R$.
> b) Suppose that $\alpha,\beta \in R$ begin:
> $$\alpha=(2,-1,1,3,6,2462456426,\frac{531441}{16807},...)$$
> $$\beta=(-4,3,5,-6,2,\frac{15625}{14641},1508975315,...)$$
> Without using a calculator, compute $(a+I)+(\beta+I)$ and $(a+I)(\beta+I)$ in the quotient ting $\frac{R}{I}$ and express each in the form $\gamma+I$ for a suitable $\gamma \in R$.

a) was easy. I don't need to worry about that.

b) I know that $(a+I)+(\beta+I)$ means that we have $(a+b)+I$. Basically we want to figure out the "shifting" we need to do to $(a+b)$ to make it part of $I$ if my intuition is correct. So we need to shift $(a+b)$ by the first $4$ terms of $\alpha + \beta $. We don't really care about the other terms so this means that something like $(-2,2,6,-3,0,0,0,...)$ which is the result of $(a+I)+(\beta+I)$ should be the correct way to approach this.

I would do a similar thing for $(a+I)(\beta+I)$ but here I multiply the elements. So here, I would get $(-8,-3,5,-18,0,0,0...)$.

Is this the correct approach?

Additionally, after the 4th term, I don't think all the entries must be $0$. In theory, I guess they could technically be anything. Is my intuition right here?

If my method is wrong, how would I approach this?